# What is a JavaDoc component for Anylogic?

Tags: java, javadoc, anylogic

I am trying to export my component in Anylogic and I need to export also a help file for it. Anylogic automatically  creates a jar component but it doesn't create a Help for it. When I look at the help for Anylogic, it says that one of the possible reasons is due to the absence of a "JavaDoc component" on the computer. What is the JavaDoc component and where can I download it for Windows?

Tried to search and found nothing. I found a Maven javaDoc plugin, but I can't understand how to connect (install) it to Anylogic.

Comment: Could you link the specific documentation that said that. The javadoc tool is part of the JDK. You'll need to run it explicitly (or configure whatever you use the generate the JAR to run it for you), and - obviously - you'll also need to add Javadoc comments to get anything useful out of it. (To be clear, I'm not familiar with AnyLogic, but a glance at their documentation shows they use Java itself, and I guess an IDE based on Eclipse.)

Comment: Specifically, did you tick the box "Generate javadoc" as shown [here](https://anylogic.help/advanced/libraries/exporting-a-library.html)?

Comment: Yes, I click exactly to this box. But I didn't see any file at the export folder except my jar file. When I read Anylogic Help, I see such comment: https://anylogic.help/anylogic/troubleshooting/troubleshooting.html#Javadoc_is_not_generated_for_my_library

Comment: So, have you checked if your Java `bin` directory is on the `PATH` as suggested by that troubleshooting document? (And it must be a JDK, not a JRE, otherwise it doesn't include `javadoc.exe`.) You can check if it is by opening a (new) command prompt and running `javadoc -h`.

Comment: Thank you! Yes the problem was in the Path variable

Comment: can you post the final solution as your own reply so others can benefit from it in the future, pls? @ЮрийЛитвин

Comment: Final solution So, have you checked if your Java bin directory is on the PATH as suggested by that troubleshooting document? (And it must be a JDK, not a JRE, otherwise it doesn't include javadoc.exe.) You can check if it is by opening a (new) command prompt and running javadoc -h.